# Did the flex display affected the img height?

Tags: html, css, image, styles, height

'Please i'm a newbie don't mind my ignorant question. click the link for proper view [https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GHAIMDPTQD2W'](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GHAIMDPTQD2W%27)
'My question is, what's the actual height the  container is using for the '. box-sizing?

Comment: the link says: "The file you asked for does not exist"

Comment: If you could provide your code for your problem in your question, it will help others understand your problem in the event that any linked code is no longer accessible.